# CSS bottom behavior does not work properly and its cutting on the right

Tags: html, css

I have the following div and the CSS assigned to it but it is not showing it properly, it shows the gap to the Left and on the right side, it is cutting the button.

```css
#cookieAlert {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border-top: 10px solid #f8f8f8;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 10px solid #111;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.left-box {
  flex: 1;
  color: #f8f8f8;
}

.right-box {
  flex: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <div id="cookieAlert">
    <div class="left-box">
      <div>This website uses cookies for functionality, analytics and advertising purposes as described in our <a href="" target="_blank" class="preen">Privacy Policy</a>. </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-box">
      <button class="ok-button" id="acceptButton" data-id="5395">OK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have used the above CSS to display in the bottom but the margins are behaving odd and not aligning it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the container to include the padding in the 100% width (otherwise it's *added* to the 100%, which makes the content go out of the container):

edit/addition after comment: To have spaces to the left and right, use a `width` less than 100% (in my edited example `width: calc(100% - 30px);`) and an according `left` setting (in my example `left: 15px;`)

```css
#cookieAlert {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 15px;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border-top: 10px solid #f8f8f8;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 10px solid #111;
  z-index: 10000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left-box {
  flex: 1;
  color: #f8f8f8;
}

.right-box {
  flex: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <div id="cookieAlert">
    <div class="left-box">
      <div>This website uses cookies for functionality, analytics and advertising purposes as described in our <a href="" target="_blank" class="preen">Privacy Policy</a>. </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-box">
      <button class="ok-button" id="acceptButton" data-id="5395">OK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: box-sizing: border-box; did the trick,  but still there is no space on the left and the right side, i tried adding left and right but right does not work.

Comment: I added settings and an explanation for a gap at the left and right to my example.